# How to prevent application's locale changing when user changes Windows date/time format (C++, Windows native app)

Tags: c++, windows, locale, rogue-wave

Our application is a Windows native 64 bit application developed in C++ (Visual Studio) with RogueWave's Stingray library, itself using MFC for the UI.

In the application, dates are shown in various places (grids, dialog box controls etc.).
As it is a complex business application, we handle the date format selection internally:
The user is able to configure the date format that is being used and we set it programmatically via the applications global locale on startup and whenever the user changes it.

For this we use _tsetlocale(LC_ALL, strLocalLng) and the Stingray RWLocaleSnapshot feature.

Now what happens is when the user opens Windows 10 Date/Time settings and modifies its date format, then immediately, some of our app's dialog box controls change to view the date in the new format!
What seems like a cool feature is difficult to handle.
We don't want the Windows settings to interfere with the configuration the user set in the app.

The thing is i don't even know what to look (google) for.

What mechanism is it that affects and sets my applications locale and gets forwarded to dialog controls immediately when the user modifies Windows settings?

And how can i prevent it?

Comment: Which dialog box controls?

Comment: Windows notifies your application with a message of the change, which probably gets forwarded to child and owned windows, which then update themselves using current locale based formatting. I'm not too familiar with it, but check if you receive WM_SETTINGSCHANGE (with thre respective WPARAM), and/or WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST

Comment: @john: In dialogs, It's a Stingray SECDateTimeCtrl. The grid views are derived from Stingray CGXGridHandleView.

Comment: @peterchen: Thanks. I'm indeed able to catch WM_SETTINGCHANGE (and ignore it). But i realize my problems go beyond that: The components will still use the Windows system date format whenever they are redrawn for other reasons.

Comment: Avoid parsing strings, [use this](https://docs.roguewave.com/en/stingray/current/Stingray_Studio_API_Documentation/Toolkit/secdatetimectrl__getdatetime.htm).

Comment: @Hans Passant: It isn't about parsing, but about how dates are displayed.

Comment: @Scrontch: that's probably a roguewave - specific question that I'n mot familiar with.